# Make it so only I can access fstab despite other users having sudo

Tags: linux, mount, sudo

I have a server that multiple users access. On that server a CIFS drive is mounted through fstab.

Mounting the CIFS drive requires sending the password in plaintext. This is not something I can change.
Multiple users require sudo access, unfortunately this also cannot change.

Of course, root owns /etc/fstab, which has my password in it.

Is there any way to keep other users with sudo access from reading /etc/fstab?

Comment: Does the drive have to be mounted with _your_ account specifically? (As opposed to a task-specific account or even the machine's AD account.)

Comment: @grawity that's a good point, and definitely something I will look into

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your password in `/etc/fstab`.  Read the man page for `mount.cifs` and note the section on credential files:

> credentials=filename|cred=filename
>
> specifies a file that contains a username and/or password and 
>     optionally the name of the workgroup. The format of the
>                    file is:
>
> ```
>          username=value
>          password=value
>          domain=value
> ```

Create a file `/root/.smbcredentials` and `chmod` it:

```
# touch /root/.smbcredentials; chmod 600 /root/.smbcredentials
```

Now edit it and store your username and password in it:

```
# vi /root/.smbcredentials
```

Examine the permissions one more time to make sure they're correct:

```
# ls -l /root/.smbcredentials
-rw------- 1 root root 31 Oct 31 09:59 /root/.smbcredentials
```

Now in `/etc/fstab`, remove your password from the CIFS mount line and use something like this instead:

```
//cifs-server/share  /media/share  cifs   noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,username=myusername,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials         0       0
```

Once you have verified that this method works, an even better approach would be to use @grawity's suggestion and create a dedicated role account with its own password, and use that account to authenticate for purposes of mounting the CIFS share.  As much as possible, **limit** that account to being unable to do much more than authenticate to the SMB/CIFS server.  Then if your sudo users read your `/root/.smbcredentials` file, they won't gain **your** password, they'll only gain the password for the limited-access service account.

Comment: That adds indirection, but users with Sudo can still access the credentials file, no?

Comment: @BrydonGibson Yes, was just thinking about an edit re: that.  You may need to tighten your sudo permissions.  Or, create a new account on the CIFS server/AD domain/whatever and mount the share under THAT username instead of yours.  Other than that, if you trust your users with sudo, then you have to trust your users with everything.

Comment: More info: [*Can root/superuser read my read-protected files?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117150/108618)